# Is there any way to render two or more templates from one component? Angular2

Tags: angular

As I am creating components through cmd (ng g component test), it will create .css .html and .ts files for that particular test component.

I want to render two different templates based on some conditions.

As by default it will render own html template, along with that I want to render different template. So can I add one more html file in same component and render that??

So, is there any way to render **two or more templates** from one component?

Comment: please show what you have done so far.  people are not going to do research without you showing some effort?  Have you tried something, do you get some exceptions?

Answer (score 2):

You can create two component with different template and call these other component from your father component like this:

```
@Component({
    selector: 'data-list',
    template: `
        <childComponent1></childComponent1>
        <childComponent2></childComponent2>
     `
})
```

ChildComponent1:

```
@Component({
selector: 'childComponent1',
template: `
    <h1>Hiiiiiiii</h1>
`
})
```

ChildComponent2:

```
   @Component({
    selector: 'childComponent2',
    template: `
    <h2>I'm second component</h2>
          `
    })
```

This is the unique way to use two or more templates in same component with Angular.

Comment: Thank you. So here we have created two components and rendered these two templates in parent component. My question is can we create two templates in one component (two html file in one component) and render those on the basis of some condition. Let's say on some if condition template1 should render and on else template2 should render.