# Angular2 how to render different template based on activatedRoute's queryParams

Tags: angular

I have a component that currently loads a particular template, templateA when the `/load-users` url is loaded.

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-load-users',
  templateUrl: './load-users.component.html',
})
export class LoadUsersComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {...}
```

I want to load a very similar template, if the url is slightly different, e.g. `/load-users/new=true`. The current component code can be reused, except for a few changes, it's just the new template that needs to look a little different. How can I load a different template based on the value of the query parameter `new`?

```
if (new) {
    show new template
} else {
    show current template
}
```

I looked around and it seems that having a separate component is advice, but I would be repeating a lot of code. Any suggestions would be helpful.

Suggestion of just having another component are abundant, is this the only way?

[Is there any way to render two or more templates from one component? Angular2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48647501/is-there-any-way-to-render-two-or-more-templates-from-one-component-angular2)

Answer (score 0):

You can have only one template per component.
But you can use `<ng-template>` to render different stuff.

`load-user.component.ts`

```
export class LoadUsersComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  new: Boolean

  someData: any;
  .
  .
  .
}
```

`load-user.component.html`

```
<div *ngIf="new; else theOtherTemplate">
  <child-component-with-the-first-template [data]="someData"></child-component-with-the-first-template>
</div>
<ng-template #theOtherTemplate>
  <child-component-with-the-first-template [data]="someData"></child-component-with-the-second-template>
</ng-template>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try using the param as some type of boolean indication for what to show on the template

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-load-users',
  templateUrl: './load-users.component.html',
})
export class LoadUsersComponent implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  isNew: boolean = false;
  constructor(private activatedRoute: ActivatedRoute) {}

  ngOnInit() {
    this.activatedRoute.queryParams.subscribe(params => {
      isNew = params['new'];
    }
  }
}
```

than in the html use something like:

```
<div *ngIf="!isNew>
  <original-template></original-template>
</div>
<div *ngIf="isNew>
  <new-template></new-template>
</div>
```

making the new template into a component would be a good idea in my opinion and helps with keeping the code concise and organized